# Run/Emulate Tomcat Server in Weblogic

Tags: tomcat, weblogic

Firstly, I realise that Tomcat and WebLogic are both servlet containers that essentially do the same thing.

We are required to run our application on WebLogic (not our choice).

There are a number of things that are a real pain to get working on weblogic and some things such as `jasig CAS` that simply don't work.

Is there a way to get WebLogic to emulate/run Tomcat in some way?

Comment: If you have a specific question on something not working I'm sure someone could help. But I believe the short answer is No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if WebLogic (or any servlet container) said that it could emulate Tomcat (or any other Servlet container), I wouldn't trust it, at all.  Tomcat varies slightly from micro-version to micro-version and of course also behaves slightly differently depending on what OS (and OS version) and JVM version it's running under, and what config.  The devil is in the details when switching from one Servlet container to another, and it's the details that are probably giving you the trouble in the first place.

And after all, Tomcat and WL already both "emulate" (so to speak) the current Servlet spec.  That's about all the "emulation" you can expect, which is why I'd say, pretty confidently, that what you're looking for isn't possible.  (But, as @better-use-mkstemp says, workarounds for various issues are likely doable.)